# ffmpeg forward stream have 3 seconds delay

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg

I am using nginx with module [nginx-rtmp-module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) as a live server.

here is the sample config.

```
    application src {
        live on;
        exec /usr/bin/ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://localhost/src/$name -acodec  copy -vcodec copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name
    }
    application hls {
        live on;
        hls on;
        hls_path /tmp/hls;
        hls_fragment 2s;
        hls_playlist_length 8s;
```

I use ffmpeg forward stream and it has about 3 seconds delay between `src` channel and `hls` channel.

The reason of delay seems to be ffmpeg itself.

Are there any methods to reduce the delay when using ffmpeg forward stream?

Any idea about it? Thanks.

Comment: this is the nginx-rtmp-module stat page screen. http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/79565610gw1f0fe2zusbdj213108o0w8.jpg  Connection time difference 3s between  two streams.

Comment: hey @lovedboy, you probably want to optimise the ffmpeg command with a smaller latency (and smaller caching buffers) see here for more details: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Latency

Answer (score 2):

The HLS format feature. It is not possible to reduce the lag to zero. This because of the server creates a playlist which is read by client and read video/audio data. So, there is at least 1 file to reproduce.

use `hls_fragment` and `hls_playlist_length` to decrease or use RTMP (FLV) data format.
read here
https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/378

Comment: But my question is the delay from rtmp stream. I use ffmpeg forward rtmp stream1 to  rtmp stream2 and stream2 backward stream1 3s.